# x-editable sends empty field although "savenochange" is set to true

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple fields being edited with x-editable, saving them all at once after a submit button was clicked, based on this example:

https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord

This is the code handling the saving process:

```
    $('.lpeditable').editable({
      url: "/post",
      savenochange: true
    });

    $('#save-btn').click(function() {
      $('.lpeditable').editable('submit', {
        url: '/post',
        data: {
          sub: $('#_sub').val()
        },
        ajaxOptions: {
           dataType: 'json'
        },
        success: function(data, config) {
          console.log("Success:");
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errors){
          console.log(errors);
          if(errors.responseText == "missing-sub"){
            console.log("Sub missing!!");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

On post it gets JSON encoded and saved into a database, when the page is loaded it gets read from the database and the page gets updated with following js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lpeditable').each(function(e) {
      var dname = $(this).attr('data-name');
      var fields = <?php if(!empty($fields)) { echo json_encode($fields); } ?>;

      if(fields !== undefined || fields !== null){
        if(fields[dname].length > 0){
          $(this).html(fields[dname]);
          $(this).removeClass('editable-empty');
        }
      }
      else {
        //
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Everything seems to work fine, except if I edit only one value it sends an empty string ("") for every other value. Savenochange seems to have no effect at all.

I also tried this approach:

```
 $('.lpeditable').editable({
      url: "/post",
      savenochange: true
    }).on('save', function(){
      var dataJ = {};
      $('.lpeditable').each(function(){
        var currAttr = $(this).attr('data-name');
        dataJ[currAttr] = $(this).editable('getValue');
      });
      $.ajax({
        url:"/post",
        data: dataJ,
        sub: $('#_sub').val(),
      })
    });
```

But it sends this:

```
{"headline":{"headline":""},"headline2":{"headline2":""}}
```

So it seems like

```
$(this).editable('getValue');
```

Is not returning anything, it is empty aswell.

Any way to not overwrite unchanged values with empty ones?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add

```
$(this).eq(0).data('editable').value = fields[dname];
```

to the js function updating the text on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lpeditable').each(function(e) {
      var dname = $(this).attr('data-name');
      var fields = <?php if(!empty($fields)) { echo json_encode($fields); } ?>;

      if(fields !== undefined || fields !== null){
        if(fields[dname].length > 0){
          $(this).html(fields[dname]);

          $(this).eq(0).data('editable').value = fields[dname]; // <-- There

          $(this).removeClass('editable-empty');
        }
      }
      else {
        //
      }
  });
});
```

This sets the value which x-editable is accessing when it saves / updates a value. This was empty before, so I set it myself. Now it's working wonderfully.

Code for the saving process stayed the same as the first version I posted.